# How to deploy a module that I am working on?

Tags: python, module

I am working on a monolithic module inside my sandbox:

```
/sandbox
   foo.py
   bar.py
   mymodule.py
```

To use my module globally I would like to install it in my machine. However I still want to be able to modify it.

What is the correct workflow for this?

I guess I eventually want to do something like:

```
echo "print 'foo'" >> my module.py
git commit -m "Added foo" .
make install
# ! oups
git checkout head~1
make install
```

I have read on many places that I will need `__init__.py` somewhere in my working directory. How do I configure it?

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks for your very short advice. Unfortunately all I understand is that I need to install `Egg`, `pip`, `setuptools`. I would be very sad if I require that huge arsenal just to install my library. What would be the essential steps I'll  need to achieve what I expressed on my question?